# Avatar for Django

Tags: django, gravatar, avatar

I need to implement avatar in my application. I see there's django-avatar but maybe there are other solutions. I need upload new avatars and resize it to a standard resolution if they're too big.

Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with [django-avatar](https://github.com/ericflo/django-avatar).

Answer (score 2):

If your main concern is handling the image size and resolution you should take a look at these two packages:

- [easy-thumbnails](http://packages.python.org/easy-thumbnails/usage.html)
- [sorl-thumbnails](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#template-examples)

[easy-thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) comes with a `ThumbnailerImageField` that automatically resizes an uploaded image for you.

> You can use the ThumbnailerField or
>   ThumbnailerImageField fields (based on
>   FileField and ImageField,
>   respectively) for easier access to
>   retrieve (or generate) thumbnail
>   images, use different storages and
>   resize source images before saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [django-avatar-crop](https://github.com/zen4ever/django-avatar-crop).

Answer (score 0):

Using gravatar is really easy with [django-gravatar](https://github.com/nvie/django-gravatar). Personally I hate uploading new profile images to every single site...

Example usage to display 40x40 thumbnail of the user's gravatar:

```
{% load gravatar %}
{% gravatar_for_user request.user 40 g %}
```